# OOP applied principles of passing data in to functions and a logical workflow

Tags: php, oop

So - I'm finally dipping my toes in to the OOP world of PHP and I think I have the hang of the basics but I feel like I might be over complicating things a bit.

I have a class that I'm writing to generate dynamic forms. It does everything I want it to but a lot of the values I'm passing in are nested arrays. It's a great way to structure the data and have a high level of control but I'm sure there are a lot of things I don't know that could help me here. I've read up on OOP, I've read plenty of examples, namespace, defining variables, passing data, the uses for OOP vs functions but I'm not really sure which direction to go. I'm just looking to see if any of you more experienced peeps would pass the data in differently?

One of the reasons I'm using the arrays is "complicated simplicity". By that I mean that it is complicated to write an array for each element but it's more simple than calling a function and having to define, in order, 14 variables. That would be a lot to remember and leave a lot of room for error in my opinion.

The class isn't very big but it's not easy to read in this medium so I have broken it up in to chunks to help organize.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Calling my class**

```
# form gen array 
$frmatts = array("name" => "testfrm", "action" => "http://jimmy.com", "class" => "Frm-cb");
# form attributes
$frmarr = array("attributes" => $frmatts);
# generate form
$frm = new form("testfrm", $frmarr);
# first element attribute 
$frmel1 = array("attributes" => array("type" => "hidden", "name" => "curstatus", "value" => "1"));
# add element to form 
$frm -> addElement("input", "curstatus", "Status", $frmel1);
echo $frm -> getForm();
```

**declarations**

```
class form{

/*
    GENERAL
        Created 11/23/15
        Initial goals are to create forms with dynamic inputs
        Potential future goals are to be able to take in current forms and parse in to arrays/variables for dynamic adjustments

    CLASS RULES
        Array grouping where possible.
        In lieu of nested arrays, outside arrays are stored in separate variables.

    ELEMENT RULES
        Every element requires a name to be reaccessed later on for editing
*/

private $attributes = array(
    "name" => "",
    "id" => "",
    "class" => "",
    "action" => "",
    "title" => "",
    "rel" => "",
    "required" => "",
    "confirm" => "" # custom attr to set jquery confirm message
);
private $properties = array();
private $elements = array();
private $title = "";

private $default_struc = array(
    "label" => "",
    "attributes" => array(
        "name" => "",
        "id" => "",
        "class" => "",
        "title" => "",
        "rel" => "",
        "required" => ""
    ), #end attributes
    "properties" => array(
        "disabled" => false
    ) #end properties 
);
private $input_struc = array();
private $select_struc = array();
private $optgroup_struc = array();
private $option_struc = array();
private $button_struc = array();
```

**__construct**

```
function __construct($title, $arr = ""){
    #set up the variables and arrays to have default data. useful for comparing values down the road.
    $this -> input_struc = array_merge($this -> default_struc, $this -> input_struc);
        $this -> input_struc['attributes']['type'] = "";
        $this -> input_struc['attributes']['value'] = "";
    $this -> select_struc = array_merge($this -> default_struc, $this -> select_struc);
    $this -> optgroup_struc = array_merge($this -> default_struc, $this -> optgroup_struc);
    $this -> option_struc = array_merge($this -> default_struc, $this -> option_struc);
    $this -> button_struc = array_merge($this -> default_struc, $this -> button_struc);

    $this -> title = $title;

    # $arr represents the attributes and properties of the form 
    foreach($arr['attributes'] as $k => $v) $this -> setAttribute($k, $v);
}
```

**basic functions**

```
function setAttribute($k, $v){#no arrays
    $this -> attributes[$k] = $v;
}

function setAttArr($inp){
    foreach($inp as $k => $v) $this -> setAttribute($k, $v);
}

function setProperty($k, $v){#no arrays
    $this -> properties[$k] = $v;
}

function setPropArr($inp){
    foreach($inp as $k => $v) $this -> setProperty($k, $v);
}

function setClass($inp){ # accepts string of classes with spaces - no arrays
    $this -> attributes['class'] = $inp;
}

function addElement($type, $name, $label, $values){#adds a new element -- $type input, select, option, optgroup, textarea, etc

    # format the attributes
    foreach($values['attributes'] as $k => $v) $elattributes .= "$k = '$v'";
    # format the properties
    if(!empty($values['properties'])) foreach($values['properties'] as $k => $v) $elproperties .= "$k = '$v'";

    switch($type){
        case 'input':
            $label = "<label>$label</label>";
            $el = "<input type = '$type' $elattributes $elproperties>";
            break;
        case 'select':
            break;
        case 'optgroup':
            break;
        case 'option':
            break;
        case 'textarea':
            break;
        case 'button':
            break;
    }
    $this -> elements[$name]['el'] = $el;
    $this -> elements[$name]['la'] = $label;
}
```

**putting the form together**

```
function getForm(){
    if(!empty($this -> title)) $title = "<h1>" . $this -> title . "</h1>";
    foreach($this -> attributes as $k => $v) if(!empty($v)) $attributes .= "$k = '$v'";
    foreach($this -> properties as $k => $v) if(!empty($v)) $properties .= "$k = '$v'";
    foreach($this -> elements as $e) $elements .= $e['la'] . $e['el'];
    return "<form $attributes $properties>
            $title
            $elements
        </form>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look (for example) at zend framework 2 forms at http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html

It will give you a good understanding of how they setup their code (applying filters/validators/ and object binding). Then dive into the framework code to see how the logic works.